# Arclength, finding definite integral

Tags: integration, arc-length

Find the length of the segment between $x=5$ and $x=2$ for the following curve.
$$f(x)= \frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{1}{4}\log\left(x\right)$$
My working so far.
$$f'\left(x\right)=x-\frac{1}{4x}.$$
Then
$$L = \int _2^5\:\sqrt{1+\left(f'\left(x\right)\right)^2}\,dx
=\int _2^5\:\sqrt{x^2+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16x^2}}\,dx.$$

However I have no idea how to find the solution to the definite integral.

Comment: $\int _2^5\:\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{16}{x^2}}$ is wrong

Comment: Fixed that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. We have that
$$1+\left(x-\frac{1}{4x}\right)^2=\frac{(4x)^2+16x^4-8x^2+1}{(4x)^2}=\frac{16x^4+8x^2+1}{(4x)^2}=\left(\frac{4x^2+1}{4x}\right)^2.$$

Comment: How did you find this?

Comment: Did you equate everything to a common denominator or use another method?

Comment: @Phun Just expand the square and then factorize.

Answer (score 0):

$$L = \int _2^5\:\sqrt{1+\left(f'\left(x\right)^2\right)}
\\
\\=\int _2^5\:\sqrt{1+\left(x-\frac{1}{4x}\right)^2}\\
\\=\int _2^5\:\sqrt{1+x^2-\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{(4x)^2}}dx\\
=\int _2^5\:\sqrt{x^2+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{(4x)^2}}dx\\
\\=\int _2^5\:\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{4x}\right)^2}\\
=\int _2^5\:|x+\frac{1}{4x}|dx \to (2<x<5) \\
\int _2^5\:(x+\frac{1}{4x})dx$$